# How to know/explore the correct/should-be content of CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER option array to get the content of a specific url by php-curl extension?

Tags: php, curl, php-curl

php manual defines `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER` as *An array of HTTP header fields to set, in the format array('Content-type: text/plain', 'Content-length: 100')* at https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php

What is this actually? Is this the one sent by my browser or the response one by the server I visit?

How do i know/explore the correct/should-be content of `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER` option array to get the content of a specific url by `php-curl` extension?

as an example, if I would want to get content of *domain.com/thepage*, how should I fill my `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER` option array?

Comment: "Is this the one sent by my browser or the response one by the server I visit?" Neither. It's what you send to the server. Your browser has nothing to do with this and you can't dictate the server's response. We can't tell you which specific header some random server expects, if any. Only you can know this. If you don't, ignore the parameter.

Comment: thanks Peter, i just wonder the methodology. for example which point should i observe while i make f12 in firefox and can observe lots of things in developer mode?

Comment: i voted my q to be closed since it's duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39047502/how-to-make-a-curl-request-that-produces-the-same-response-headers-as-firefox